# How do I convert an expression from infix to prefix?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am a class 12 student from ISC 2022 batch, and this is my first question on Stack Overflow.

Recently this problem has been confusing me a lot, and I am finding different answers in the internet.

How do we convert an expression from **infix** to **prefix** in Java? For example, if the expression is `(X+Y)/(Z*W/V)`, what is it's equivalent **prefix** expression?

My doubt focuses on the question that if while scanning, if incoming operator is of SAME precedence as that of **top of the stack** `(TOS)`, then should we push it?

Or should we pop the `TOS` and check incoming operator with next `TOS`?

My computer teacher has taught us the latter, whereas in several sources like **geeksforgeeks** and **javatpoint**, I am finding the former method.

Please could someone clarify my doubt once and for all?

Answer (score 0):

For infix to prefix conversion, the following steps can be followed:

1. Reverse the *infix* string.
2. Convert the modified string to postfix. `(` must be handled as `)` & `)` as `(`.
3. Reverse the obtained expression to get the *prefix* expression.

But for *infix* to *postfix* conversion, when the current token is an operator, we keep appending the tokens to the postfix expression, while `precedenceOf(currToken) <= precedenceOf(stack.peek())`.
But for conversion to prefix expression, due to the reversal of the infix string, the left to right associativity gets disturbed.
So, to maintain the *associativity*, when the incoming character is of the same precedence order:
push it into the stack, rather than popping out the top element from the stack.
Example:

```java
infix = (X + Y) / (Z * W / V)  
prefix = /+XY/*ZWV
```

`(X+Y)/(Z*W/V)` => `(+XY) / ((*ZW)/V)` => `(+XY) / (/*ZWV)` => `/ +XY /*ZWV`
*Brackets are only for illustration.